# javascript hide() show() div is blinking with mozilla

Tags: javascript, css

I made simple slideshow today and I saw, that the slides are blinking when changing with mozilla. How to fix it?

HTML:

```
<div class="full_slider">
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00049.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00050.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00051.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00052.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00053.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00054.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00055.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00056.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00057.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00058.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00059.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00060.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00061.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00062.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00061.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00060.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00059.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00058.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00057.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00056.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00055.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00054.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00053.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00052.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00051.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00050.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div style="background: url(images/background/10_00049.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>
                </div>
```

JS:

```
$(".full_slider > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('.full_slider > div:first')
    .hide()
    .next()
    .show()
    .end()
    .appendTo('.full_slider');
},  83);
```

JS code is generating 12 slides per second, how to fix that problem with blinking?

Comment: The time on your setInterval is 83ms. Doesn't that need to be longer? Like 2000ms?

Comment: no, i need that the sliders slide very fast

Comment: Please use CSS for styling your div's instead of inline styling for every div

Comment: AnaMaria, it is not neccassary, and btw I'm using CSS, becouse every div is diferent

Comment: @baitas212123 only url is changing. other properties like `background-repeat` , `background-position` are same. Go through this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background). you are repeating so much of code. (I know it is not related to your question, just can't tolerate you are going in wrong direction which annoys other developers like me.)

Comment: ok, I did that, thanks, but this is not a fix for blinking problem :/

Comment: have you tried `fadeOut("slow")` & `fadeIn("slow" )` instead of `hide` and `show`?

Comment: i don't need slow efect everything should be pass very fast, thats why i'm using show() hide()

Comment: I have a feeling it might be to do with the fast setInterval time and browser lag. Have you tried a slower time like 1000 to see if it blinks then?

Comment: yes, i tried, when the interval is slower, the lag has gone and the blinking was fixed, but i need that interval (83ms)

Comment: In that case, it's probably to do with browser lag. The browser can't keep up with what the code is asking so it's freaking out. It's putting too much strain on the browser and this would be particularly bad on old browsers or slow computers. As such I'd suggest finding a completely different way of achieving what you want.

Comment: meybe you have what to offer for me? becouse i thought it was the greatest idea, but there isnt...

Comment: Well if the images are moving that fast I'm asuming it'll look almost like an animation or flick book. (I may be wrong about that). But if that's the case, you could try a single animated gif image, flash, css3 animation of various elements making up the image, or jQuery animation.